# Click function is not working after changing the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a basic image upload script, when i click on case-img1, it basically trigger file input that is hidden, after selecting the file, it changes next div(case-img2) class(img-upload-enable) to allow choosing next file, But when i click on the div after changing the class it doesnt work

```
<table id="choose-photos-tb">
 <tr>
   <td><div id="case-img1" class="img-upload-enable">+</div></td>
   <td><div id="case-img2" class="img-upload-disable">+</div></td>
   <td><div id="case-img3" class="img-upload-disable">+</div></td>
   <td><div id="case-img4" class="img-upload-disable">+</div></td>
   <div id="case-image-inputs">
     <input type="file" name="case_img1" id="case_img1" accept="image/*">
     <input type="file" name="case_img2" id="case_img2" accept="image/*">
     <input type="file" name="case_img3" id="case_img3" accept="image/*">
     <input type="file" name="case_img4" id="case_img4" accept="image/*">
   </div>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.body).on('click', '.img-upload-enable', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if (id == "case-img1"){
            $('#case_img1').trigger('click');
            $("#case_img1").change(function() {
                $('#case-img2').attr("class", "img-upload-enable");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @empiric all the ids are unique but not class

Comment: What do you expect to happen when clicking on the 2nd plus sign? You only check for `(id == "case-img1")` in your condition which is not true for the second element. Or did you just omit some code here? P.S. disregard my previous comment, I misread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your logic is because after the first cycle the condition: `id == "case-img1"` is never true.

You can fix this and improve the DRYness of the logic by using common classes. You can then relate each file trigger to the file input by their indexes.

Also note that your HTML is invalid; the `div` cannot be a child of the `tr`. It needs to be within its own cell.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $triggers = $('.case-img-trigger');
  var $inputs = $('.case_img');
  
  $(document).on('click', '.img-upload-enable', function() {
    var index = $triggers.index(this);
    var $target = $inputs.eq(index).trigger('click');
  });
  
  $inputs.on('change', function() {
    var index = $inputs.index(this);
    $triggers.eq(index + 1).toggleClass('img-upload-disable img-upload-enable');
  });
});
```

```css
.case-img-trigger {
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-upload-enable {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="choose-photos-tb">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="case-img-trigger img-upload-enable">+</div>
      <div class="case-img-trigger img-upload-disable">+</div>
      <div class="case-img-trigger img-upload-disable">+</div>
      <div class="case-img-trigger img-upload-disable">+</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="case-image-inputs">
        <input type="file" name="case_img1" class="case_img" accept="image/*" />
        <input type="file" name="case_img2" class="case_img" accept="image/*" />
        <input type="file" name="case_img3" class="case_img" accept="image/*" />
        <input type="file" name="case_img4" class="case_img" accept="image/*" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are missing the `change` function if that is relevant to the OPs logic, your script immediately enables the next input on click and not after a file has been added to the input

Comment: Thanks. I put that under the wrong event. Answer updated

Comment: Thanks, Ill try to understand it step by step as i'm very new

Comment: No problem. The important methods which make this work are [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index) and [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq)

Comment: How does eventListener work? Does it check for the class of clicked object when the event happens ? Or stores all the objects with given class when the listener gets defined?
This question came to my mind because when we define this listener , the next object in this example that we wanna change its class ,has no  the triggering class. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: `Does it check for the class of clicked object when the event happens?` yes, that's right. It's a delegated event handler that's assigned to a parent element. So it relies on the event bubbling up the DOM to be handled when the element's attributes match the selector provided

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if i want to add a function inside the change function to preview the image, as im adding this readURL($inputs.eq(index)); is $inputs.eq(index) right ?

Comment: Just `$(this)` will get you a reference to the changed file input.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of tying together both the right file select field, and the next button to enable using `data-*` attributes and use these to trigger the click, and change the classes.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.img-upload-enable', function(){
    var id = $(this).data("upload");
    $(id).trigger("click");
});

$(document.body).on("change","input[type=file]",function(){
   var id = $(this).data("next");
   $(".img-upload-enable").removeClass("img-upload-enable").addClass("img-upload-disable")
   $(id).removeClass("img-upload-disable").addClass("img-upload-enable");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="choose-photos-tb">
 <tr>
   <td><div id="case-img1" class="img-upload-enable" data-upload="#case_img1">+</div></td>
   <td><div id="case-img2" class="img-upload-disable" data-upload="#case_img2">+</div></td>
   <td><div id="case-img3" class="img-upload-disable" data-upload="#case_img3">+</div></td>
   <td><div id="case-img4" class="img-upload-disable" data-upload="#case_img4">+</div></td>
   <div id="case-image-inputs">
     <input type="file" name="case_img1" id="case_img1" accept="image/*" data-next="#case-img2">
     <input type="file" name="case_img2" id="case_img2" accept="image/*" data-next="#case-img3">
     <input type="file" name="case_img3" id="case_img3" accept="image/*" data-next="#case-img4">
     <input type="file" name="case_img4" id="case_img4" accept="image/*">
   </div>
 </tr>
</table>
```